# How can I do a regex search recursively from a directory?

Tags: shell-command, grep, find-dired, find

Basically I want a command that can do the following:

`find /path/dir -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -l "foo"`

Is there an emacs command to do this? If not, then is there a convenient keybinding that I can make? I tried to do the following:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-f") 'find)
(defun find (dir string)
  (interactive)
  (shell)
  (insert "find")
  (insert dir)
  (insert "-type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -l")
  (insert string)
)
```

But it doesn't seem to work. It gives me "wrong type argument: commandp, find".

Answer (score 1):

The following does that and presents the results as a `dired` buffer:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `find-grep-dired`

You'll also want to know about:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `rgrep`

(which doesn't support the `-l` option to grep, but is usually what I want from a recursive regexp search.)

Answer (score 1):

@phils answered the question. This is just to say that the version of `find-grep-dired` in library [`find-dired+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/find-dired%2b.el) provides a bit more than the vanilla version:

- It has two optional args, `DEPTH-LIMITS` and `EXCLUDED-PATHS`.
- The `interactive` spec uses `read-from-minibuffer`, `read-file-name`, `dired-regexp-history` and `find-diredp-default-fn`.

> **`find-grep-dired`** is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
>   [`find-dired+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/find-dired%2b.el).
>
> `(find-grep-dired DIR REGEXP &optional DEPTH-LIMITS EXCLUDED-PATHS)`
>
> Use Dired on the list of files in `DIR` whose contents match `REGEXP`.
>
> The `find’` command run (after changing into `DIR`) is essentially this,
>   where `LS-SWITCHES` is `(car find-ls-option)`:

```
find . \( -type f -exec grep grep-program find-grep-options -e REGEXP {} \; \) LS-SWITCHES
```

> Thus `REGEXP` can also contain additional `grep` options.
>
> Optional arg **`DEPTH-LIMITS`** is a list `(MIN-DEPTH MAX-DEPTH)` of the
>    minimum and maximum depths.  If `nil`, search directory tree under `DIR`.
>
> Optional arg **`EXCLUDED-PATHS`** is a list of strings that match paths to
>    exclude from the search.  If `nil`, search all directories.
>
> When both optional args are non-`nil`, the `find` command run is this:

```
find . -mindepth MIN-DEPTH -maxdepth MAX-DEPTH \( -path EXCLUDE1 -o -path EXCLUDE2 ... \)
       -prune -o -exec grep-program find-grep-options -e REGEXP {} \; LS-SWITCHES
```

> where `EXCLUDE1`, `EXCLUDE2`... are the `EXCLUDED-PATHS`, but shell-quoted.